# Switching Easily between Remote Desktop Windows

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am controlling many Remote Desktops from a single workstation.
I find it tedious to minimize RDC Window 1 and Maximize RDC Window 2 to switch between them every time. 
Is there an easier way to switch between full screen RDC's ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that using the [remote desktop connection manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21101) is the way to go.

Comment: However, I have some trouble on Full Screen with mutliple monitors. It does not seem to be able to adapt the client area to the available space on the screen, and it does not use all the available monitors as in native full screen mode

Comment: If you need to I think you can right click on the server and undock it and move it to the second monitor and have the others still within the manager. Also each server has properties that are either inherit or not. Lots can be done with it but it definitely is quite helpful for me with 90+ servers and virtual servers.

Comment: Sure. But What I need is to span one RDC through all my monitors in full screen, as if it was my main workstation actually (which is the default behavior when I open a simple mstc